# CryptoJS encrypt HMACSha256 different than Java

Tags: java, kotlin, encryption, hmac, cryptojs

I'm trying to convert this code of CryptoJS to Kotlin:

```js
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(message, key); 
const signature = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
```

That's the kotlin code equivalent to above snippet:

```
private fun generateSignature(key: String, payload: String): String {
    val algorithm = "HmacSHA256"

    return Mac.getInstance(algorithm)
        .apply { init(SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), algorithm)) }
        .run { doFinal(payload.toByteArray()) }
        .let { HexUtils.toHexString(it) }
}
```

But it is not working at all. They generate different results. CryptoJS generates an array of bytes that has 8 positions, the Java code generates an array of bytes that has 32 positions.

I don't know what Im doing wrong. I need to make my Kotlin code work exactly as the javascript one.

Update: I can't change the Javascript way. I have to do the exactly same thing in Kotlin

Update2: Here is a test where the JS code and the Kotlin code generates different results.

Input:

```
key = 's21fk4vb-5415-46c7-aade-303dcf432bb4'
message = 'POST,/wallets/3323461f96-bdf3-4e03-bc93-7da1fb27aee7/withdraw/,1573148023809,{"amount":"1.0","bank":{"bank":"789","agency":"456","account":"12378","accountDigit":"6","name":"joao","taxId":"33206913098","holderType":"personal"}}'
```

Results with JS code:

```js
Result of encrypt in bytes:
{sigBytes: 32, words: [8]}
sigBytes: 32
words: [8]
0: 2102759135
1: -196086391
2: -2099697915
3: -1620551271
4: 2463524
5: 1757965357
6: -1039993965
7: -1798822705

Bytes to Hex:
7d558edff44ff58982d927059f6859990025972468c86c2dc202f39394c824cf
```

Results with Kotlin code:

```
Result of encrypt in bytes:
{byte[32]@1126} 
 0 = 82
 1 = -110
 2 = -100
 3 = -128
 4 = -63
 5 = 22
 6 = -103
 7 = -31
 8 = 83
 9 = -125
 10 = -72
 11 = 109
 12 = -91
 13 = -69
 14 = 54
 15 = -41
 16 = 27
 17 = -107
 18 = -60
 19 = -110
 20 = -57
 21 = -29
 22 = -20
 23 = -32
 24 = -66
 25 = 88
 26 = 87
 27 = -50
 28 = -47
 29 = -18
 30 = -96
 31 = 25

Bytes to Hex:
52929c80c11699e15383b86da5bb36d71b95c492c7e3ece0be5857ced1eea019
```

Comment: I tried your code in a JSFiddle and I got "88cd2108b5347d973cf39cdf9053d7dd42704876d8c9a9bd8e2d168259d3ddf7" as result. Are you sure the problem doesn't exist elsewhere?

Comment: Hi, the js code and the kotlin code works. Both generate a signature. But if i test with the same input they generate different signatures

Comment: Running your JS&data on nodejs 12.9.1 cryptojs 3.1.9-1 **I get a different result** 52929c80c11699e15383b86da5bb36d71b95c492c7e3ece0be5857ced1eea019
 which agrees with your Kotlin result _and_ my results from Java and OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1):

No SHA-256 hash can have only 8 byte positions. The output, as the name suggests, should be 256 bits or 32 bytes. What I suspect to happen is that the input of `stringify` is already presumed to be bytes, while CryptoJS functions return a `WordArray` of 32 bit words. As 8 * 32 = 256 this seems reasonable.

So I presume you can simply fix this by using a function on the `WordArray` instead, for instance `hash.toString('hex')`.

Comment: could you also suggest to fix the variable names? hash != hmac.

Comment: I think you just did :). HMAC value is a keyed hash value, so I didn't find it that important. `tag` would be another option, or just `mac`, etc.

Comment: I can't change the Javascript way. I have to do the exactly same thing in Kotlin

Comment: Can you show me the input and output string of JavaScript?